# Use sed to replace $ in a tcl script

Tags: sed

I have a file which contains following:

```
@$test123
@$test456
$test789
```

In tcl shell, I want to replace `^$`,
I tried following but it doesnt seem to work:

```
eval exec grep test file | sed s/^\$//
@$test123
@$test456
$test789
```

I should see the `$test789` replaced with just `test789`

Answer (score 0):

Since `$` has a special meaning in a regex (line end/file end), it has to be quoted or provided as character class.

This does what you want:

`sed -e 's/^[$]//g'`

Comment: I  have tried that but get following error:

eval exec grep test file | sed -e s/^[$]//g

Error: unknown command '$'

P.S. I am trying to run this in Tcl shell. Could that cause some issue ?

Comment: Well probably since I tested it on a Linux shell and know that it works. Try `\$` instead of the character class.